# Configure checkstyle method names for @Test methods only

Tags: java, regex, checkstyle

Is it possible to define the checkstyle MethodName module in order to verify a diferent regex for @Test methods?

My configuration now is:

```
<module name="MethodName">
  <property name="format" value="^(may_or_may_not_)?[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$"/>
</module>
```

This means that methods can have may_or_may_not_ in the beginning. I'd like to know if its possible to have such a check in @Test methods only.

thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible. You will have to write a custom check, let's say as a subclass of *MethodName*, which adds an annotation based filter.

Comment: It would theoretically be possible to define a RegExp check instead of MethodName, but this will not work reliably if other annotations are used in addition to `@Test`.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own CustomizedChecker class which extends MethodNameCheck.

In you class implementation:

you only need to overwrite one method:

- ```java
  /**
   * Called to process a token.
   *
   * @param ast the token to process
   */
  public void visitToken(DetailAST ast) {
      // No code by default, should be overridden only by demand at subclasses
  }
  ```

The method implementation will have following logic:

1. get the MODIFIERS_DEF from the method definition which is `DetailAST ast` in the parameter because annotations used are stored in the MODIFIERS child for the METHOD_DEF as you can referred from the documentations in `TokenTypes`
2. check that @Test is in the modifier definition
3. perform your method check

For example:

```java
public class JUnitTestMethodNameFormatChecker extends MethodNameCheck {
    public static final Set<String> testAnnotationNames = Stream.of("Test", "ParameterizedTest").collect(Collectors.toSet());

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST methodAST) {
        if (methodAST.getType() == TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF) {
            // 1
            List<DetailAST> methodAnnotations = CheckUtils.getAnnotationModifiers(methodAST);
            String methodName = methodAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT).getText();
            // 2
            boolean hasTestAnnotation = methodAnnotations.stream().anyMatch(a -> testAnnotationNames.contains(a.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT).getText()));
            if (hasTestAnnotation) {
                // 3 perform your method name check here
            }
        }
    }
}

public class CheckUtils {
    public static List<DetailAST> getAnnotationModifiers(DetailAST ast) {
        List<DetailAST> res = new ArrayList<>();
        if (ast.branchContains(TokenTypes.MODIFIERS)) {
            TokenUtil.forEachChild(ast.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.MODIFIERS), TokenTypes.ANNOTATION, res::add);
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```